# count how many tasks is open or onhold for logged in user

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create Sql script to see how many task open or on-hold only for logged in user who assigned
to task 
result 
HelloWorld1(0)
HelloWorld2(2)
HelloWorld3(1)
HelloWorld4(5)

```
SELECT Projects.projectID,
    Projects.projectName + ' ' + '(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID)) + ')' AS Project
  FROM Projects
  LEFT JOIN Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID
 INNER JOIN Users_projects ON Projects.projectID = Users_projects.projectID
 INNER JOIN Tasks ON Projects_tasks.taskID = Tasks.taskID
 INNER JOIN Users_Tasks ON Tasks.taskID = Users_Tasks.TaskID
 WHERE Users_Tasks.userID = @userID
   AND Tasks.status = 'Open'
   AND Tasks.status = 'Onhold'
 GROUP BY Users_projects.userID,
          Projects.projectName,
          Projects.projectID,
          Users_Tasks.userID
```

[image]

Comment: For the record, your question doesn't read like a question at all.  Next time, indicate what isn't working so we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

```
AND (Tasks.status = 'Open' AND Tasks.status = 'Onhold')
```

Which can't be true; a Task can't have both values at the same time.  You want:

```
AND (Tasks.status = 'Open' OR Tasks.status = 'Onhold')
```

Better yet, use `IN`:

```
AND (Tasks.status IN ('Open', 'Onhold') )
```

Answer (score 0):

No row will be able to match:

```
(Tasks.status = 'Open' AND Tasks.status = 'Onhold')
```

Try

```
(Tasks.status = 'Open' OR Tasks.status = 'Onhold')
```

Or:

```
Tasks.status in ('Open', 'Onhold')
```

Answer (score 0):

As already commented, the `AND` clause can not be satisfied as `Task.Status` can be only either **Open** or **OnHold**. Use the following code:

```
SELECT Projects.projectID,
    Projects.projectName + ' ' + '(' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COUNT(Projects_tasks.taskID)) + ')' AS Project
  FROM Projects
  LEFT JOIN Projects_tasks ON Projects.projectID = Projects_tasks.projectID
 INNER JOIN Users_projects ON Projects.projectID = Users_projects.projectID
 INNER JOIN Tasks ON Projects_tasks.taskID = Tasks.taskID
 INNER JOIN Users_Tasks ON Tasks.taskID = Users_Tasks.TaskID
 WHERE Users_Tasks.userID = @userID
   AND (Tasks.status = 'Open' OR Tasks.status = 'Onhold')
 --also this code can be used: 
 --AND Tasks.status in ('Open', 'Onhold')
 GROUP BY Users_projects.userID,
          Projects.projectName,
          Projects.projectID,
          Users_Tasks.userID
```